# How long does it takes for a transaction proposal to be shown in the Web and Mobile interfaces?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm proposing transactions as a no-owner using the delegate feature.

```
const safeService = new SafeServiceClient('https://safe-transaction.mainnet.gnosis.io');
await safeService.proposeTransaction({
    safeAddress: SAFE_ADDRESS,
    safeTransaction: safeTx,
    safeTxHash: txHash,
    senderAddress: DELEGATE_ADDRESS
});
```

When this is complete, the transaction is now listed as a pending transaction in the service API but is not shown in the Web/Mobile interface.

After 10 minutes or so the transaction appears on both frontends. Is this time normal? I would like to send an email notification to the Safe's owners when the transaction is ready to sign. Should I wait 10 minutes or is there a way to check the API the frontend is using?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Transaction needs to be signed so it appears on the interface. If not, it will only show when transaction gets executed. When proposing a transaction, check: https://safe-transaction.mainnet.gnosis.io/api/v1/safes/SAFE_ADDRESS/all-transactions/?executed=false&queued=true&trusted=true

That's the filter the UI is using. If you don't sign the transaction, it will not be `trusted` (as any person could propose a transaction for your Safe), you can check using:

https://safe-transaction.mainnet.gnosis.io/api/v1/safes/SAFE_ADDRESS/all-transactions/?executed=false&queued=true&trusted=false